# Symfony generate several forms with a twig loop

Tags: forms, symfony, loops, twig

Can anybody tell me why this code is not working, I do not find an example of this on internet.

```
{% for dp in dpList %}
            <tr>
              <td> //values </td>
              <td>....</td>
               ...
              <td>
                {{ form_start(display) }}
                {{ form_row(display.info, { value: dp.info }) }}
                {{ form_rest(display) }}
                {{ form_end(display) }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

What I am trying to do is to show a button "Display" for each row which contains a hidden value of this row. It actually only shows the button into the first row.

Thanks!

Comment: Just make many form objects in your controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that suits my needs:

I create a form in a private function:

```
private function formShow()
    {
        $show = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('admin_platform_show'))
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('persno', 'hidden')
            ->add('Show', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        return $show;
    }
```

Then in my controller I create an arrayList with a loop on each row I will have, so it will generate as much as forms that I need:

```
foreach ($idmList as $idm) 
{
    $show = $this->formShow()->createView();
    $arrayForms[] = $show;
}
```

Then I send my arrayList to my view and access each form like this:

```
{{ form_start(arrayForms[loop.index0]) }}
{{ form_row(arrayForms[loop.index0].persno, { value: idm.persno }) }}
{{ form_rest(arrayForms[loop.index0]) }}
{{ form_end(arrayForms[loop.index0]) }}
```

That way I use a secured form made by symfony, containing a specific value of the row that I will reuse in another controller if I press the submit button.

Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: Thank you man! I did something similar and I added the formView directly to my array of object as an attribut!

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. A form object is a single instance of the form, you can't render it multiple times on the same page.

You should either have multiple form objects, or use something else instead of forms, like a link or a button with javascript.

I suggest using jQuery and the `post()` function.

Comment: I wanted to use form because of the security it provides:
<input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="b32edfab46bba2a778e64f7eb183d0ed12b4c237" />

Comment: You could have a button that sends a POST request in the same way, using AJAX. Edited answer with suggestion.